# Difference between running maven tests via intellij and command line

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, allure

I've setup a maven project which complies and runs selenium tests both via Intellij and terminal. Test framework is TestNg and I'm using allure report to see test results. I've owerwritten onTestFailure and added take annotated(Attachment) screenShot method in it. My question is, whenever I run tests via Intellij it successfully captures screenshot and adds to attachment file, while the same doesn't happen via terminal. Currently I'm on a Mac machine, but the same happens on windows machine. Any hint what is the difference and how to solve this?

Comment: Without pom file, java version, the test code etc. it's possible to see/guess what the differences are?

Comment: @khmarbaise does the pom file take place? the same pom file should apply for both ways. Nope?